# Techniques of molecular medicine/biology for aesthetic medicine?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, medicine, epigenetics, biomedical-engineering

Are there scientifically valid methods (possibly in the developmental stage) that can be used for aesthetic medicine. Usually surgical of physical therapies are used for aesthetic medicine, but actually all the problems of aesthetic appearance should be traceable to the genetic/epigenetic causes and that is why the molecular treatment at that level should be possible and optimal.

My question is can be considered also as a veterinary medicine question (aesthetics of pets) and that is why it is really a biology question.

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2470289718787086 is the only more or less relevant article that I have managed to find.

Also CRISPR can be quite promising tool, but I have not managed to find scientific studies for aesthetic medicine of it.